# How to configure subdomain for Azure DCOS?

Tags: azure, dns, marathon, dcos

I've installed my application on azure DCOS container service. I use marathon-lb to map docker containers to the external point. Config looks like:

```
"labels":{
    "HAPROXY_GROUP":"external",
    "HAPROXY_0_VHOST":"mycustomename-devagents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com",
    "HAPROXY_0_MODE":"http"
  }
```

Is it possible to map different service to `api1.mycustomename-devagents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`, `api2.mycustomename-devagents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`?

Or better map services directly to 
`api1.my-site.com`. `api2.my-site.com`?

Comment: Can you please explain how you did this?

Comment: @happy I use comma-separated list of domains.

Comment: Did you configured any CNAMEs in azure? and also did you used DCOS templates to setup?. Can you please elaborate on the answer? Because I have used DCOs template and marathon-lb but unable to access via url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from doing that, add a cname alias to `api1.my-site.com` pointing to `api1.mycustomename-devagents.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com` and you are done.

Comment: I've found that marathon-lb is smart enough to parse this:
`"HAPROXY_0_VHOST": "api2.my-site.com"`